# Props are undefined in the child component when it is created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I got "`artists` prop is Undefined" error in the console

[image: console output showing "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop artists. Expected Array, got Undefined"]

Structure of components:

`Discover` > `ArtistSlider` > `ArtistItem`

`Discover` passes the prop `artists` to `ArtistSlider` and it does it only when all the data is received from API. But `ArtistSlider` throws the error that prop `artists` is undefined for some reason. At the same time, `ArtistItem` doesn't throw an error despite it is the child of `ArtistSlider` and it receives the prop `artist` from `ArtistSlider`.

I read about vue lifecycle but still cannot get why it happens. Especially in the middle of the ​component tree.

Discover:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Discover page</h1>
    <artist-slider :artists="collection.new_artists"/>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import store from "@/store";
import Page from "@/mixins/Page";
import ArtistSlider from "@/components/ArtistSlider";

export default {
  extends: Page,
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const collection = await store.dispatch("fetchUrl", {
      url: "discover",
      params: { location: "uae" }
    });
    console.log('Received collection from API', collection)
    next(vm => (vm.collection = collection));
  },
  components: {
    ArtistSlider,
  },
  created() {
    console.log('Discover Created', this.collection)
  }
};
</script>
```

ArtistSlider:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <h2>New Artists</h2>
    <ul>
      <artist-item
        v-for="artist in artists"
        :key="artist.slug"
        :artist="artist"
      />
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import ArtistItem from './ArtistItem'

export default {
  name: "AppArtistSlider",
  props: {
    artists: {
      required: true,
      type: Array
    }
  },
  components: {
    ArtistItem
  },
  created() {
    console.log('Slider Created', this.artists)
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

ArtistItem:

```html
<template>
  <li>
    <app-image :src="artist.avatar.small" :alt="artist.full_name" /> 
    <h3>{{artist.full_name}}</h3>
    <p>{{artist.art_type.name}}</p>
  </li>
</template>

<script>
  import AppImage from './AppImage.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'ArtistItem',
    props: {
      artist: {
        required: true,
        type: Object
      },
    },
    components: {
      AppImage
    },
    created() {
      console.log('Item Created', this.artist)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Will apreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Inside `ArtistSlider` change `<ul>`  to `<ul v-if="artists">`. Please check and confirm

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This throws the same error. Btw, I can set a default value to `() => []` in `props` and it works. However, I'm just trying to realize how it works and why it happens in order to find a better solution.

Comment: I guessed it is because the value of collection is got asynchronously. When the `ArtistSlider` be created, the props `artist` has not been obtained from API yet. So, the value of props `artist` is undefined.

Comment: It's happening because of asynchronous nature of it. But setting default value to empty array would work.